# WP Shortcodes not being added

Tags: wordpress

I was creating a wordpress plugin where the user enters in some information, and is able to generate shortcodes. I was not quite sure where the shortcodes are supposed to go - my current setup is class-based, and I want to be able to create a shortcode when an AJAX request is being made, and is successful. The following two methods are in the same file in the class.

This method gets called via the admin-ajax.php file:

```
public static function processAjax()
{

    global $wpdb;
    $event_data = $_POST['obj'];

    $event_title = $event_data[0];
    $event_subdomain = $event_data[1];
    $result_events = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_shortcode_plugin WHERE subdomain = '{$event_subdomain}'", OBJECT);
    if (sizeof($result_events)>0) {
        echo "duplicate";
    } else {
        add_shortcode($event_subdomain, 'getEmbed');
        $results = $wpdb->insert('wp_shortcode_plugin', array("event_name"=>$event_title, "subdomain"=>$event_subdomain));
        echo json_encode($_POST['obj']);
    }

    die();
}
```

And here is my getEmbed() method that I would like to call.

```
public static function getEmbed()
{
    return 'test';
}
```

It seems that the shortcodes are not being created, however. Am I missing something here? Also, is it possible to pass a value to the getEmbed function from the add_shortcode() method?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding shortcode directly from AJAX, you should use `update_option` to store in the information for the shortcode to be loaded.  If option doesn't exist, it will be created.

Than you will simple use `wp_init` hook to load up all of the shortcodes you need to load in the `function.php` file for the theme or plugin php file.

You should use `get_option` within the `wp_init` hook and check the values in there.  You will need to have function(s) associated with the shortcodes, which can be autogenerated in php using `create_function` or you can route them through 1 function (defined in your php file) that will have the `$atts` and `$content` parameters defined and do whatever depending on the value of your `get_option` that you send to that function.

`add_shortcode` function should be defined within the `wp_init` hook, after checking the value of the `get_option` function.  You will need to give your option a name and add to it via the ajax function.  the option will most likely want to be an array, that wordpress will automatically serialize.  Than you use that array returned from `get_option` to loop through the array of shortcodes, and call `add_shortcode` as many times as you need there.  This requires setting up your option array so that it has a shortcode tag defined in each index of the array.  I would, personally, make the shortcode tag the key of the array and all attributes of the shortcode, imo, would than be an array of that array.

Hope this helps you to get started on this.

Comment: Why can't you just use the add_shortcode() call from within the processAjax() method? I know that it works from within the constructor, but I would like to be able to add the shortcode on the fly...Also, wouldn't the wp_init hook to load all the shortcodes in function.php only run upon initialization? The idea is that the user

Comment: `add_shortcode` AFAIK gets loaded during content initialization. I don't think you can add it anywhere you want and expect it to work.  Everywhere I've seen it used is in the functions.php file to load the shortcode needed automatically for it to be used globally.  Putting `add_shortcode` into ajax function does not add the shortcode globally for `the_content` to use.

Comment: Technically, you don't even need to put it in `wp_init` hook.  Should be able to just put it in the `functions.php` or plugins php file directly.  Check if the option exists, and do whatever based on that.