# Wordpress plugin - can't create shortcodes from within a class

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I stored an array in the wordpress database with shortcodes I want to create.  I want to read the array of shortcodes and create them on my wordpress site using class functions from a class that is not instantiated.  (I'm new to classes in PHP, so tried to keep it as simple as possible)

Array structure stored in the wordpress database:

```
my_array = [ 
'code1' => 'text_to_replace1', 'show1' => 'text_to_show1',
'code2' => 'text_to_replace2', 'show2' => 'text_to_show2',
 ];
```

I'm using code like this to try to create the shortcodes:

```
add_action( 'admin_init', ['my_class','register_shortcodes'] );
```

and the functions inside the class are:

```
class my_class {
  private static $codes = [];

  static function register_shortcodes() {
    self::$codes = get_option('my_options_in_database');
    add_shortcode( $codes['code1'],['my_class', 'render_shortcode1'] );
    add_shortcode( $codes['code2'],['my_class', 'render_shortcode2'] );
  }

  static function render_shortcode1() {
    return self::$codes['show1'];
  }

  static function render_shortcode2() {
    return self::$codes['show2'];
  }
}
```

The code appears to half-run, because the shortcode is being created (as viewed by another plugin showing me active shortcodes), but the shortcode doesn't do anything.  The text is never replaced.
For example, if the shortcode stored in 'code1' = 'foo', and 'show1' = 'bar' and I have this on one of my pages in the website
`This is what [foo] looks like` it is never replaced by the correct text in 'show1'.

I've tried many variations and looked up many articles, like this one:
[Create a shortcode for a handmade plugin in Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49239726/create-a-shortcode-for-a-handmade-plugin-in-wordpress)
or this one:
[WP Shortcodes not being added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34980907/wp-shortcodes-not-being-added)

Nothing seems to address this exactly, and because no errors are thrown, I have no idea why it isn't working.  I would really appreciate some pointers here.

ALSO:  I haven't figured out how to pass arguments to my functions inside the class when calling them this way.  If I knew that, I could have a single function render all my shortcodes, so that would help too.  Any info on that would also be appreciated.  I can create a separate question for that if needed.

Comment: where do you want this shortcode to work : admin or front or both ? where yo you put your shortcode : editor or with in php code ? 
Because `admin_init` will only add your shortcode in the admin area. Use init `instead`. If you try to use it directly in php you have to use `<?php echo do_shortcode('[code_to_replace]'); ?>` for example.

Comment: @AlexisVandepitte I want it to work in front.  I just want to set it up in the admin area.  Thank you!!  That helps immensely!  Once I figure out how to pass a parameter when calling my method ```render_shortcodes()``` my plugin should be working completely.  Calling it in this manner ```add_shortcode( $codes['code1'],['my_class', 'render_shortcode1'] );``` doesn't accept any parameters that I can see.  Go ahead and list your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to register a shortcode, do not use `admin_init` but `init`. Even if you want to set it up in the admin area. Because WordPress does not store in the database what you register, the code that register the shortcode is read at each page load.

With the `admin_init` hook the shortcode will only be registered in the admin area but not on the front.